# replacing a string with a list of indexes

Tags: python

I am making a hangman game but I cannot seem to figure out why I cannot replace the underscores with the right letter. I tried using lists incase there is more than one of the same letter. I used a temporary word so I do not have to guess each time.

An example of the output would be:

> ***_ _ _ _ _***
>
> {}
>
> guess a letter:t
>
> t _ _ _ _
>
> {}
>
> guess a letter:

etc

````
incorrectGuesses = set()


hangmanDrawingCount = 0
temp = ("tempp")
indexList = []
while True:
   print(hangmanList[hangmanDrawingCount])
   (len(incorrectGuesses) == 0):
       underscoreGuess = (len(temp)*" _")
       print(underscoreGuess)
       print("\n{}")   
   else:
       print(underscoreGuess)
       print(incorrectGuesses)
   userGuess = input("guess a letter:")
   if(userGuess in temp):
       for i in range(len(temp)):
           if (temp[i] == userGuess):
               indexList.append(i)

   
               
       
       
   else:
       incorrectGuesses.add(userGuess)
       hangmanDrawingCount+=1
        ```
````

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Your code doesn't actually work, but if the syntax errors are fixed, it's pretty clear you only print `underscoreGuess` and `incorrectGuesses`, but never update `underscoreGuess`, so it makes sense it doesn't change when you print it?

Comment: you can have a simple string underscoreGuess,and the udpate it when a correct letter is guessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rebuild the entire string each time it changes.

Since you want to print the word with spaces in between the letters, you might have an easier time using a list, like this:

```
answer = "tempp"
incorrect_guesses = set()
word = ["_"] * len(answer)

while True:
    # print(hangmanList[len(incorrect_guesses)])
    print(" ".join(word))
    if "_" not in word:
        print("You win!")
        break

    if incorrect_guesses:
        print(incorrect_guesses)
    guess = input("guess a letter: ").lower()
    if guess in answer:
        word = [a if guess == a else w for w, a in zip(word, answer)]
    else:
        incorrect_guesses.add(guess)
```

```
_ _ _ _ _
guess a letter: a
_ _ _ _ _
{'a'}
guess a letter: o
_ _ _ _ _
{'o', 'a'}
guess a letter: p
_ _ _ p p
{'o', 'a'}
guess a letter: e
_ e _ p p
{'o', 'a'}
guess a letter: t
t e _ p p
{'o', 'a'}
guess a letter: m
t e m p p
You win!
```

Answer (score 0):

just use slicing my guy

```py
for i, letter in enumerate(answer):
        if answer[i] in correct:
            underlines = underlines[:i] + answer[i] + underlines[i+1:]
```